# Using Google Assistant Change Firebase Database Value

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assist-api

I Created a android app in which if a press a button and value changes in Firebase database (0/1) , i want to do this using google assistant, please help me out, i searched out but didn't found any relevant guide please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The code to do this is fairly straightforward - in your webhook fulfillment you'll need a Firebase database object, which I call `fbdb` below. In your Intent handler, you'll get a reference to the location you want to change and make the change.

In Javascript, this might look something like this:

```
app.intent('value.update', conv => {
  var newValue = conv.prameters.value;
  var ref = fbdb.ref('path/to/value');
  return ref.set(newValue)
    .then(result => {
      return conv.ask(`Ok, I've set it to ${newValue}, what do you want to do now?`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error( err );
      return conv.close('I had a problem with the database. Try again later.');
    });
  return 
});
```

The real problem you have is what user you want to use to do the update. You can do this with an admin-level connection, which can give you broad access beyond what your security rules allow. Consult [the authentication guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#admin-sdk-authentication) and be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on a project using Dialogflow webhook and integrated Firebase database. To make this posible you have to use the fulfilment on JSON format ( you cant call firebasedatabase in the way you are doing)

Here is an example to call firebase database and display a simple text on a function.
First you have to take the variable from the json.. its something loike this (on my case, it depends on your Entity Name, in my case it was "tema")

```
var concepto = request.body.queryResult.parameters.tema;
```

and then in your function:

```
    'Sample': () => {
 db.child(variable).child("DESCRIP").once('value', snap => {
 var descript = snap.val(); //firebasedata
          let responseToUser = {
              "fulfillmentMessages": [
                  { //RESPONSE FOR WEB PLATFORM===================================
                      'platform': 'PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED',
                      "text": {
                          "text": [
                              "Esta es una respuesta por escritura de PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED" + descript;
                          ]
                      },
                  }
              ]
          }
          sendResponse(responseToUser); // Send simple response to user
 });
      },
```

these are links to format your json:
Para formatear JSON:

A) https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Platform

B) https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Message#Text

And finally this is a sample that helped a lot!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuKPQJoHJ_g

Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

after searching out i find [guide](https://www.hackanons.com/2018/07/iot-with-firebase-home-automation-light.html) which can help on this :

- we need to first create chat bot on dialogflow/ api.pi
- Then need to train our bot and need to use webhook as fullfillment in
  response.
- Now we need to setup firebase-tools for sending reply and doing
  changes in firebase database.
- At last we need to integrate dialogflow with google assistant using google-actions

Here is my sample code i used :

```
`var admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var database = admin.database();
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
let params = request.body.result.parameters;
database.ref().set(params);
response.send({
speech: "Light controlled successfully"
});
});`
```